# Add a limited cross site question feed to the main page

Tags: feature-request, tags, feed, site-crossover

Often people have lamented the "this is appropriate on multiple sites, but people yell if I post copies of it on both" or "I'd post it on the other site, but it doesn't get enough eyeballs - this one gets more (even though its off topic here)".  This is a problem.

The answer to this problem would be to get the eyeballs from here to there.  Some chatrooms do this.  For example, the [photography chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/14/photography-chat?tab=feeds) has Software Recommendations photography tag as part of its feed and [gardening chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/546/the-garden-shed?tab=feeds) has the gardening tag from Sustainability.  There are other examples out there too.

And while this helps the active members of chat get to other sites, the active members of chat are often a small minority of the site as a whole and don't constitute that many eyeballs.

So, on the right hand side of the main page/questions side of the site, have a 'recent questions on other sites' that consumes the feed for a specific tag on the other site.  So that the photography main page will see the questions tagged as photography on software recommendations... and maybe they'll want the lenses tag from physics.SE too.  And likewise, gardening and sustainability can cross promote each other's site.  And AskUbuntu can take note of the ubuntu tag on unix.SE and so forth.  There are lots of cross site possibilities.

A key point to consider is that the more involvement with stack exchanges as a whole, the more likely that a person is likely to remain on stack exchange and contribute (a good thing).  Furthermore, having this cross site tags of interest may help avoid verbatim cross posts (a bad thing) and at the same time provide new users with "oh, there's a stack exchange for that over there too?" when considering where to ask questions - because they see it on the front page.

This list of cross site tags of interest would be maintained by the mods on the site.

Comment: There's still the issue of volume to consider. "Give us only the five highest-voted [tag:tag] questions of the day" should be part of the setup. Otherwise, I fully support this, or any feature that makes the ongoing network fragmentation bareable, and interdisciplinary questions tenable.

Comment: I feel this would only be useful in limited cases... for example, there's a **huge** overlap between Movies & TV and Sci-Fi/Fantasy. But, on M&TV, we **do not** use genre tags in general. This means that we'd have to somehow categorize every film title that falls into the Sci-Fi or Fantasy category... and keep it up for every future title as well or the feature is useless. They use the chat feature but they get very few questions, generally only a couple of identify-this-movie questions, which aren't really the sort of question they really want to see.

Comment: @Catija it depends on how in tune the sites are with each other, and if the two communities *want* to share their eyeballs beyond the chat room. Yes, it will imply some tighter couplining between the tags of the two sites than the minimal "question must have a tag that exists on target to migrate" that is currently the case. If M&TV wants their sci-fi questions to show up on Sci-Fi, they would need to tag it in a way that is meaningful to the other community. There may need to be an 'ignored tags' that squashes questions of certain tags to not be seen on the other site.

Comment: I don't think tags are an issue, necessarily. I assume that the "imported" questions are marked clearly as such, so different tagging won't matter. Of course, it could be possible to define rules of the form "import tag [X] from site Y, and add virtual tags [a] and [b]". cc @Catija

Comment: I would emphasize the bit "So, on the right hand side of the main page/questions side of the site, have a 'recent questions on other sites' that consumes the feed for a specific tag on the other site" - the idea I had in mind isn't questions showing up in the main 'feed' but rather on the side in the vicinity of the hot questions.